# Render columns on jQuery accordion collapse bars?

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm using a jQuery accordion widget, so the text that goes on the collapse bars needs to go inside `<h3>` tags.  My collapse bars contain three separate pieces of related information (file name, size, and date).  I'd really like these three items to be rendered at the left, center, and right of the bar, so that the fully-collapsed accordion resembles a three-column table.  Is there any way I can do this?

I tried using `float:right` (see below) to put the file name by itself at left and the size and date together off to the right.  This is not quite what I want, but I thought it would be a reasonable compromise.  However, when I expand the section, the expanded area only goes over as far as where the right-floated text begins instead of all the way across the page, which looks a little weird.  It also doesn't provide any way to left-align the floated text over multiple bars, as far as I know, since they would have to be separate `float`s each with their own width.

```
<h3>
  myfile.xls
  <span style="float:right">153 kB, 03/12/2013</span>
</h3>
```

Next, I tried adding some `padding-right` to the first two pieces of data (below).  This worked pretty well, but my choices are to specify either a fixed size, which doesn't shrink or expand with the window size; or a percent, which doesn't allow me to left-align the center or right columns over multiple bars.  I also tried putting a `width:33%` on each piece of data, which was ignored completely.

```
<h3>
  <span style="padding-right:33%">myfile.xls</span>
  <span style="padding-right:33%">153kB</span>
  03/12/2013
</h3>
```

What I'd really like is three equal-width columns, with the text left-aligned within each column.  But I'm limited by jQuery's use of the `<h3>` tag to specify what goes on the collapse bar (I even tried an inner `<table>` with one row, knowing full well that it wouldn't work inside an inline element, but hey - I had to give it a try!).  I'm required to make this work for IE 8+ and Firefox 3+, although so far both have rendered the same for the things I've tried so I don't anticipate much trouble there (knock on wood).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: I think I may have found the answer (of course, as soon as I post my question!). Is this the proper way to do it: Instead of <h3> tags to specify my collapse bar text, use <div class="ui-accordion-left"> and then <div class="ui-accordion-right"> for the content?  So now I can use a <table> inside the "left" <div>?

Comment: Seems to work, although I apparently still need to tweak the css a bit because the columns are not lining up quite right (individual tables do not have the same total width even though I'm setting them to 100%).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have three equal columns on your collapse bars, right?
Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/victmo/f2Scp/
I think you forgot to add `display:block` to your bars or columns.

Cheers

Comment: Yep, that worked!  Thanks!  I did find something else within a few minutes of posting my question (see my comment after the original question), but this is cleaner and doesn't require using jQuery's classes directly - which are a bit misleading, to be honest - why are the bars "left" and the content "right" when they will be rendered vertically?  The accordion widget does support other layouts, but the default is vertical.  Oh well, I'm new to jQuery and overall I'm impressed with how much you can do in a short time.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a treeTable? Something like http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/

Sounds like it would be easier to adapt something that already displays columnar data to be a nav control rather than trying to modify the jQuery accordion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  My employer is extremely restrictive on what plugins we are allowed bring in, but we do currently have a request in for one of the jQuery tree plugins (can't remember which one, one of my coworkers submitted the request).  I might try something like this when that gets approved.  It will definitely be useful in other areas of our web site as well.